# How to return the position of numbers, which are same as input numbers, in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, position

I have a list such as:

```
[1,2,3,2,1,5,6]
```

I want to find the all the positions of 1 in the list. I tried if statement, but I only get the position of first 1, not all 1s.

The real output if I use if statement looks like `[0]`, but the expected result should be `[0,4]`.

Comment: please share your code though it gave you wrong out put?

Comment: How these positions are going to be user? Perhaps you don't need them at all.

Comment: The problem is solved! Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) iterating over [`enumerate(your_list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and using an `if` statement as part of it to catch only the wanted values, as below:

```
data = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6] # Your list
num = 1 # The value you want to find indices for

pos = [i for i, v in enumerate(data) if v == num]
print(pos)
# [0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using enumerate:-> this give a tuple with its `index` and `value` from the list

```
 lndexs=[]
 for index,value in enumerate([1,2,3,2,1,5,6]):
        if value==1:
            lndexs.append( index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lstOfNumbers = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6]
searchFor = 1
lstOfIndexs = [index for index in range(len(lstOfNumbers)) if lstOfNumber[index]==searchFor]
```

Or you can use the python function filter

```
lstOfNumbers = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6]
searchFor = 1    
lstOfIndexs = filter(lambda x: lstOfNumbers[x]==searchFor, range(len(lstOfNumbers)))
```